# CloudFoundry force pandas version

Tags: pandas, scikit-learn, version, cloud-foundry, predix

I developed a program locally that works just fine, however when I push it to CloudFoundry/Predix, some version discrepancies make it incompatible. I'm developing locally and use a Jupyter notebook. I use some pickled files. When I check

```
import pandas as pd
pd.__version__
```

I get

```
'0.20.1'
```

HOWEVER once the app is in the cloud, it crashes. Checking the logs it gives messages like

> 2018-06-13T10:35:18.88+0200 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] ERR
>   /home/vcap/app/.cloudfoundry/0/python/lib/python3.4/site-packages/sklearn/base.py:311:
>   UserWarning: Trying to unpickle estimator ExtraTreeRegressor from
>   version 0.18.1 when using version 0.19.1. This might lead to breaking
>   code or invalid results. Use at your own risk.

So it seems like on the server, Pandas v 0.19.1 is installed. I don't understand how it thinks the pickled files were pickled with Pandas 0.18.1, as it seems to me I'm using 0.20.1. So I'm trying to force Pandas to be version .18 or .20 by putting the line `pandas==0.18.1` (or `pandas==0.20.1` respectively) in my `requirements.txt`. When doing a `cf push` I do see lines like `2018-06-13T10:18:26.81+0200 [STG/0] OUT Collecting pandas==0.18.1 (from -r /tmp/app/.cloudfoundry/0/requirements.txt (line 3))`, so it would SEEM that I'm installing version 0.18.1 to avoid compatibility issues, however the error still persists and it seems like I'm running .19 on the server. What am I missing here? How can I make sure version .18 is being used?

Comment: it's moaning about `scikit-learn` not `pandas` your pickled model is from an earlier version, you'd need to retrain your model in version `0.19.1` to match your `CloudFoundry` installed version

Comment: Aaaah you're the best! Forcing it to use SKLearn 0.18.1 did the trick. Thank you, you're very observant!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error:

> /home/vcap/app/.cloudfoundry/0/python/lib/python3.4/site-packages/sklearn/base.py:311:
>   UserWarning: Trying to unpickle estimator ExtraTreeRegressor from
>   version 0.18.1 when using version 0.19.1. This might lead to breaking
>   code or invalid results. Use at your own risk.

is moaning about `scikit-learn` and not `pandas`, it's stating that your pickled model is from an earlier version so either retrain with the version that is installed or force the version to the one that your pickled model was trained with